# Force Samba network logins

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking, samba

I'm experimenting with un secured read write samba shares

AND

secure read write samba shares.

I've worked out the required (user.group + folder perlmissions + basic smb.conf setup)

Now heres the thing, when I log into the secure samba share and close the folder. I am not challenged for username and password if I access the share again. How can I make it do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, AFAIK. Once you successfully log into another computer through Windows Explorer, the credentials will be cached *locally* (by your XP system) for the rest of your session. You would have to log out from XP to clear them.

Although I don't see why that would be a problem. If you are afraid that someone will access the secure share when you're away, just lock the PC (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

Or, if you need this for experiments with Samba, use `net use` instead: `net use \\host\share /u:username /p:no` and `net use \\host\share /d`.